# Refreshing queries with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with 5 `Access` Queries that I have pulled into Excel.  I need to make a VBA to cycle through the 5 tables and have them refresh every time it is ran. However, my code does not seem to execute and it just skips over the loop. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    UnlockSheets

    ' Update the raw data queries for needed information
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
        Range("A:AR").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

        Dim QT As QueryTables
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

        For Each QT In ws.QueryTables
            QT.Refresh
        Next QT
        Application.StatusBar = False

        Range("A:AR").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    ' Refresh the pivot tables in the worksheet "pivot"
    Worksheets("Pivot").Activate
        Dim pvtTbl As PivotTable

        For Each pvtTbl In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
            pvtTbl.RefreshTable
        Next

    ' Update the rank sheet with the needed information
    Worksheets("Rank").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
        ActiveSheet.EnableCalculations = True
        DoEvents

    LockSheets

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Should be `QT as QueryTable` singular, you have it as plural.  Try that, see if that fixes it.

Comment: I tried doing that but nothing seems to work. It just skips over the loop.

Comment: When I try and manually update the table with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("Table_Report_Database.accdb_2[[#Headers],[Date]]").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` I get a `Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out. Instead of cycling through all of the QueryTables, I made a manual fix by adding:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("Table_Report_Database.accdb_2[[#Headers],[Date]]").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```